# Flash Actionscript GetURL not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

i´m making a banner for a webpage in flash. And i want to put buttons with links there.

So far i got it working with this script:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLVariables;


fisicleta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
function onMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
    var request:URLRequest = newURLRequest("url");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    var target:String = "_blank";
navigateToURL(request, target);
}
```

But his opens the link in a new tab, and i´m trying to keep it all in the same tab. I tried changing the target to "_self" but the link goes dead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this - var request:URLRequest = newURLRequest("url") - a typo in writing the question? It should be var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url");

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("url"), "_top");
```

it will call your url from the window.top location and not from the current self location.